# Using C# and simpleJSON how do I access data in this array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, simplejson

I want to parse JSON in this format

```
    json result:{
      "time": 23,
      "npc":[
       {
        "id":1,
        "b_box" {
          "left": 250,
          "top": 135,
        },
    },
    {
       "id":2,
       "b_box" {
         "left": 234,
         "top": 343,
        },
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "b_box" {
        "left": 342,
        "right": 543,
      }
    }
   ]
  }
```

Here is my code for parsing

```
    void extractD (string jsonResult) {
         JSONNode incomingData = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(jsonResult);
         JSONArray npc = incomingData ["npc"].AsArray;
         foreach (JSONNode bBox in npc) {
               int bLeft = bBox ["b_box"]["left"];
               int bTop = bBox ["b_box"]["top"];
         }
```

I want to initialize variables with the left and top values for id:1  id:2 and id:3 separately how should I modify my code to accomplish this? Code examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: what nested array? there's only one array in the JSON...

Comment: I would project each id as a model and the entire JSON object itself as a model and have the parent model hold a list of the id models.  I would then use a method property to fetch the object with the id and check it's top, bottom, left, right values (those not populated would be null)

Comment: I do not know what you mean by project as a model do you have a link to reference material? Do you mean create a class from the JSON?

Comment: read this: http://www.tomasvera.com/programming/using-javascriptserializer-to-parse-json-objects/ it shows you how you deserialize a JSON string into class models which is what I mean, projecting the JSON string to class models.

Comment: Id just use Newtonsoft so I can deserialize that into an actual object and take that json to here : http://json2csharp.com/ and copy the object it makes for you into your source. Then you have an object that holds that array so you can do MyObject.npc[whatever].myLeft;

Comment: The json piece you posted is _not_ valid, check  [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)